# Why are my trades being closed the second it is opened?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, stock, trading, algorithmic-trading

I have a strategy that closes the second it opens.  I even have stop loss levels at 50% and they still close immediately, meaning that I am truly stuck. When using the code here

```
if longSignal
    strategy.entry("Long", strategy.long)
if shortSignal
    strategy.entry("Short", strategy.short)
if shortSignal
    strategy.close("Long")
if longSignal
    strategy.close("Short")
```

The strategy works and allows for an order to last longer than a second, but the moment I add a take profit or stop loss, it no longer wants to be kept open.

I've included a short piece of code here to show how even this doesnt work. Im not really sure why it doesnt work, as it works with an extremely basic script, but gives up as soon as I add a take profit and stop loss.

```
// Define stop loss and take profit in pips
stopLoss = 0.5 * close
takeProfit = 0.5 * close

// Enter short position when shortSignal is true
if shortSignal
    strategy.entry("Short", strategy.short)
    strategy.exit("Exit Short", "Short", stop=stopLoss, limit=takeProfit)
```

This is my signals code. Like I said before, the strategy does work on extremely basic conditions so this shows my strategy does work and allows for buying and selling, but adding stop losses and exits makes it panic for some reason.

```
//SIGNALS
bullfvgc = BullFVG and FVG
bearfvgc = BearFVG and FVG
var bullFVGCounter = 0
var bearFVGCounter = 0
var bullFVGtop = 0.0
var bullFVGbottom = 0.0
var bearFVGtop = 0.0
var bearFVGbottom = 0.0

var liquidityGrabBull = false
var liquidityGrabBear = false

var fvgDetectedBull = false
var fvgDetectedBear = false

if hour(time, 'GMT+1') >= tradeStartHour 
     and hour(time, 'GMT+1') < tradeEndHour
    if low <= asianLow and high < asianHigh
        liquidityGrabBull := true
    if high >= asianHigh and low > asianLow
        liquidityGrabBear := true

if liquidityGrabBull and bullfvgc
    fvgDetectedBull := true
    bullFVGtop := low
    bullFVGbottom := high[2]

if liquidityGrabBear and bearfvgc
    fvgDetectedBear := true
    bearFVGtop := low[2]
    bearFVGbottom := high

longSignal = fvgDetectedBull and low < bullFVGtop 
shortSignal = fvgDetectedBear and high > bearFVGbottom

isSignalTime = hour(time, 'GMT+1') >= tradeStartHour2 
 and hour(time, 'GMT+1') < tradeEndHour2

plotshape(showE?(longSignal and not longSignal[1]) and isSignalTime and close<asianHigh:na, title='LONG FVG', 
 style=shape.labelup, color=s1Col, location=location.belowbar, 
  size=size.tiny, text='L', textcolor=color.black)
plotshape(showE?(shortSignal and not shortSignal[1]) and isSignalTime and close>asianLow:na, title='SHORT FVG', 
 style=shape.labeldown, color=s2Col, location=location.abovebar, 
  size=size.tiny, text='S', textcolor=color.black)

if longSignal
    liquidityGrabBear := false
    fvgDetectedBull := false

if not isSignalTime
    liquidityGrabBull := false
    liquidityGrabBear := false

if shortSignal
    liquidityGrabBull := false
    fvgDetectedBear := false
```

here is my full code

```
//@version=5
strategy('strategy.', overlay=true, max_lines_count=500, max_labels_count=500)

// Dropdown input for selecting currency pair
currencyPair = input.string(defval="GBPJPY", title="Currency Pair", options=["GBPJPY", "EURUSD"])

// Define FVG condition values for different currency pairs
fvgCondition = currencyPair == "GBPJPY" ? 0.018 : 0.00003

// Display settings
showW = input.bool(true, title="Show Entry Signals", group="Display Settings") 
showE  = input.bool(true, title="Show Entry Signals", group="Display Settings")
s1Col  = input.color(color.green,"Long Signal Color", inline="3", group="Display Settings")
s2Col  = input.color(color.red,"Short Signal Color", inline="3", group="Display Settings")
showAL = input.bool(true, title="Show Liquidity Levels", group="Display Settings")
l1Col  = input.color(color.red,"Bottom Liquidity Level Color", inline="4", group="Display Settings")
l2Col  = input.color(color.blue,"Top Liquidity Level Color", inline="4", group="Display Settings")
l1W    = input(1, "Top Liquidity Level Width", group="Display Settings")
l2W    = input(1, "Bottom Liquidity Level Width", group="Display Settings")
showL  = input.bool(true, title="Show Liquidity Sweep", group="Display Settings")
ls1Col  = input.color(color.green,"Bottom Liquidity Sweep Color", inline="5", group="Display Settings")
ls2Col  = input.color(color.red,"Top Liquidity Sweep Color", inline="5", group="Display Settings")

//AS Liquidity Zones
asianSessionStartHour = 23
asianSessionEndHour = 8
asianSessionEndHour2 = 9
tradeStartHour = 8
tradeEndHour = 9
tradeStartHour2 = 8
tradeEndHour2 = 9

var float asianHigh = na
var float asianLow = na

if hour(time, 'GMT+1') == asianSessionStartHour and minute(time, 'GMT+1') == 0
    asianHigh := high
    asianLow := low
else if (hour(time, 'GMT+1') > asianSessionStartHour) 
     or (hour(time, 'GMT+1') < asianSessionEndHour)
    asianHigh := math.max(asianHigh, high)
    asianLow := math.min(asianLow, low)

lookBackCandles = 48
otherHighs = ta.highest(high, lookBackCandles)
otherLows = ta.lowest(low, lookBackCandles)

if hour(time, 'GMT+1') == asianSessionEndHour and minute(time, 'GMT+1') == 0 and showAL
    line.new(x1=bar_index - 1, y1=asianHigh, x2=bar_index+120, 
     y2=asianHigh, color=l2Col, width=l1W)
    line.new(x1=bar_index - 1, y1=asianLow, x2=bar_index+120, 
     y2=asianLow, color=l1Col, width=l2W)


llq = hour(time, 'GMT+1') >= tradeStartHour and hour(time, 'GMT+1') < tradeEndHour and (low <= asianLow and high < asianHigh)
hlq = hour(time, 'GMT+1') >= tradeStartHour and hour(time, 'GMT+1') < tradeEndHour and(high >= asianHigh and low > asianLow)

plotshape(showL?llq and not llq[1]:na, "Low Liquidity Sweep", shape.triangleup, location.belowbar, ls1Col, size=size.small)
plotshape(showL?hlq and not hlq[1]:na, "High Liquidity Sweep", shape.triangledown, location.abovebar, ls2Col, size=size.small)



LondonSessionStartHour = 8
LondonSessionEndHour = 15
LondonSessionEndHour2 = 16
LondontradeStartHour = 15
LtradeEndHour = 16
LtradeStartHour2 = 15
LtradeEndHour2 = 16

var float LondonHigh = na
var float LondonLow = na

if hour(time, 'GMT+1') == LondonSessionStartHour and minute(time, 'GMT+1') == 0
    LondonHigh := high
    LondonLow := low
else if (hour(time, 'GMT+1') >= LondonSessionStartHour and hour(time, 'GMT+1') < LondonSessionEndHour)
    LondonHigh := math.max(LondonHigh, high)
    LondonLow := math.min(LondonLow, low)
    
lookBackCandlesLondon = 48  
otherHighsLondon = ta.highest(high, lookBackCandlesLondon)
otherLowsLondon = ta.lowest(low, lookBackCandlesLondon)

if hour(time, 'GMT+1') == LondonSessionEndHour and minute(time, 'GMT+1') == 0 and showAL
    line.new(x1=bar_index - 1, y1=LondonHigh, x2=bar_index+120, 
     y2=LondonHigh, color=l2Col, width=l1W)
    line.new(x1=bar_index - 1, y1=LondonLow, x2=bar_index+120, 
     y2=LondonLow, color=l1Col, width=l2W)



llq2 = hour(time, 'GMT+1') >= LondontradeStartHour and hour(time, 'GMT+1') < LtradeEndHour and (low <= LondonLow and high < LondonHigh)
hlq2 = hour(time, 'GMT+1') >= LondontradeStartHour and hour(time, 'GMT+1') < LtradeEndHour and (high >= LondonHigh and low > LondonLow)



plotshape(showL?llq2 and not llq2[1]:na, "Low Liquidity Sweep", shape.triangleup, location.belowbar, ls1Col, size=size.small)
plotshape(showL?hlq2 and not hlq2[1]:na, "High Liquidity Sweep", shape.triangledown, location.abovebar, ls2Col, size=size.small)

//FVG     

FVG = input.bool(true ,'Show FVGs',group = 'FVG Settings') 
BULLfvgc = input.color(#f2ff00,'FVG Color : ',group = 'FVG Settings',inline = '1')
BEARfvgc = input.color(#f079d2,'<-- BullFVG | BearFVG --> ',group = 'FVG Settings',inline = '1')
TT = input.bool(true, 'FVG ToolTips?',group = 'FVG Settings')
bC = input.bool(true ,'Remove Bar Color?',group = 'FVG Settings') 
UTC = -5
UTC := UTC * 3600000

fTime = '\nTime : ' + str.format("{0,date," + 'hh:mm a' + "}", time[1] + UTC)

BearFVG = high < low[2] and FVG and (low[2] - high) > fvgCondition
BullFVG = low > high[2] and FVG and (low - high[2]) > fvgCondition
FVGc = BullFVG ? BULLfvgc : BEARfvgc

var label Label = na
bool BearFVGp = false
bool BullFVGp = false

if BearFVG
    Label := TT ? label.new(
     x = time[1], 
     y = math.avg(high,low[2]),
     text = '     ',
     xloc = xloc.bar_time,
     color = color(na),
     style = label.style_label_center,
     size = size.large,
     tooltip =  
     'Bear FVG\n---------------------' + 
     '\nSize : '   + str.tostring(low[2] - high) +
     '\nTop : '    + str.tostring(low[2]) +
     '\nMiddle : ' + str.tostring(math.avg(low[2],high)) +
     '\nBottom : ' + str.tostring(high) + fTime) : na
    BearFVGp := true
if BearFVGp == true and BearFVGp[1] == true 
    BearFVGp := false

if BullFVG
    Label := TT ? label.new(
     x = time[1], 
     y = math.avg(high[2],low),
     text = '     ',
     xloc = xloc.bar_time,
     color = color(na),
     style = label.style_label_center,
     size = size.large,
     tooltip =  
     'Bull FVG\n---------------------' + 
     '\nSize : '   + str.tostring(low - high[2]) +
     '\nTop : '    + str.tostring(low) +
     '\nMiddle : ' + str.tostring(math.avg(high[2],low)) +
     '\nBottom : ' + str.tostring(high[2]) + fTime) : na
    BullFVGp := true
if BullFVGp == true and BullFVGp[1] == true
    BullFVGp := false
    
bool BullGO1 = BullFVG and BullFVGp
bool BearGO1 = BearFVG and BearFVGp
bool BullGO2 = BullFVG and BullGO1 == false
bool BearGO2 = BearFVG and BearGO1 == false
    
p1 = plot(FVG ? 
 BearGO1 ? low[2] : BullGO1 ? low : na : na,
 style = plot.style_stepline,
 offset=-1,display = display.none,
 editable = false)
p2 = plot(FVG ? 
 BearGO1 ? high : BullGO1 ? high[2] : na : na,
 style = plot.style_stepline,
 offset=-1, display = display.none,
 editable = false)
fill(p1,p2,color = FVGc[1],editable = false)

p3 = plot(FVG ? 
 BearGO2 ? low[2] : BullGO2 ? low : na : na,
 style = plot.style_stepline,
 offset=-1,display = display.none,
 editable = false)
p4 = plot(FVG ? 
 BearGO2 ? high : BullGO2 ? high[2] : na : na,
 style = plot.style_stepline,
 offset=-1, display = display.none,
 editable = false) 
fill(p3,p4,color = FVGc[1],editable = false)

barcolor(color = bC and (BullFVG or BearFVG) ? color.new(color.white,100) : na, offset = -1, editable = false)

//SIGNALS
bullfvgc = BullFVG and FVG
bearfvgc = BearFVG and FVG
var bullFVGCounter = 0
var bearFVGCounter = 0
var bullFVGtop = 0.0
var bullFVGbottom = 0.0
var bearFVGtop = 0.0
var bearFVGbottom = 0.0

var liquidityGrabBull = false
var liquidityGrabBear = false

var fvgDetectedBull = false
var fvgDetectedBear = false

if hour(time, 'GMT+1') >= tradeStartHour 
     and hour(time, 'GMT+1') < tradeEndHour
    if low <= asianLow and high < asianHigh
        liquidityGrabBull := true
    if high >= asianHigh and low > asianLow
        liquidityGrabBear := true

if liquidityGrabBull and bullfvgc
    fvgDetectedBull := true
    bullFVGtop := low
    bullFVGbottom := high[2]

if liquidityGrabBear and bearfvgc
    fvgDetectedBear := true
    bearFVGtop := low[2]
    bearFVGbottom := high

longSignal = fvgDetectedBull and low < bullFVGtop 
shortSignal = fvgDetectedBear and high > bearFVGbottom

isSignalTime = hour(time, 'GMT+1') >= tradeStartHour2 
 and hour(time, 'GMT+1') < tradeEndHour2

plotshape(showE?(longSignal and not longSignal[1]) and isSignalTime and close<asianHigh:na, title='LONG FVG', 
 style=shape.labelup, color=s1Col, location=location.belowbar, 
  size=size.tiny, text='L', textcolor=color.black)
plotshape(showE?(shortSignal and not shortSignal[1]) and isSignalTime and close>asianLow:na, title='SHORT FVG', 
 style=shape.labeldown, color=s2Col, location=location.abovebar, 
  size=size.tiny, text='S', textcolor=color.black)

if longSignal
    liquidityGrabBear := false
    fvgDetectedBull := false

if not isSignalTime
    liquidityGrabBull := false
    liquidityGrabBear := false

if shortSignal
    liquidityGrabBull := false
    fvgDetectedBear := false
// Enter long position when longSignal is true
if longSignal
    strategy.entry("Long", strategy.long)

// Enter short position when shortSignal is true
if shortSignal
    strategy.entry("Short", strategy.short)

// Exit long position when shortSignal is true
if shortSignal
    strategy.close("Long")

// Exit short position when longSignal is true
if longSignal
    strategy.close("Short")
```

Comment: 1st - if longSignal will appear, then  `strategy.long` will close short position, there is no need for `  strategy.close("Short")`. other looks fine, need full code with symbol, and timeframe